# JPA double relation with the same Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have these Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Content extends AbstractEntity
{
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_CONTENT_REVISION_ID")
    private ContentRevision current;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ContentRevision> revisionList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class ContentRevision extends AbstractEntity
{
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTENT_ID")
    private Content content;

    @Column(name = "TEXT_DATA")
    private String textData;

    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "REG_DATE")
    private Date registrationDate;
}
```

and this is the db mapping:

```
CONTENT
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CURRENT_CONTENT_REVISION_ID | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

CONTENT_REVISION
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| REG_DATE                    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TEXT_DATA                   | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CONTENT_ID                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have also these requirements:

1. `Content.current` is always a member of `Content.revisionList` (think about `Content.current` as a "pointer").
2. Users can add a new `ContentRevision` to an existing `Content`
3. Users can add a new `Content` with an initial `ContentRevision` (cascade persist)
4. Users can change `Content.current` (move the "pointer")
5. Users can modify `Content.current.textData`, but saves `Content` (cascade merge)
6. Users can delete `ContentRevision`
7. Users can delete `Content` (cascade remove to `ContentRevision`)

**Now, my questions are**:

1. Is this the best approach? Any best practice?
2. Is it safe to cascade merge when the same entity is referenced twice? 
   (`Content.current` is also `Content.revisionList[i]`)
3. Are `Content.current` and `Content.revisionList[i]` the same instance? 
    (`Content.current` == `Content.revisionList[i]` ?)

Thanks

---

**@jabu.10245** I'm very grateful for your effort. Thank you, really.

However, there's a problematic (missing) case from your tests: when you run it inside a container using CMT:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTest
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()
    {
        // Create deploy file
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
        war.addPackages(...);
        war.addAsResource("persistence-arquillian.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
        war.addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        // Show the deploy structure
        System.out.println(war.toString(true));

        return war;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDetached()
    {
        // find a document
        Document doc = em.find(Document.class, 1L);
        System.out.println("doc: " + doc);  // Document@1342067286

        // get first content
        Content content = doc.getContentList().stream().findFirst().get();
        System.out.println("content: " + content);  // Content@511063871

        // get current revision
        ContentRevision currentRevision = content.getCurrentRevision();
        System.out.println("currentRevision: " + currentRevision);  // ContentRevision@1777954561

        // get last revision
        ContentRevision lastRevision = content.getRevisionList().stream().reduce((prev, curr) -> curr).get();
        System.out.println("lastRevision: " + lastRevision); // ContentRevision@430639650

        // test equality
        boolean equals = Objects.equals(currentRevision, lastRevision);
        System.out.println("1. equals? " + equals);  // true

        // test identity
        boolean same = currentRevision == lastRevision;
        System.out.println("1. same? " + same);  // false!!!!!!!!!!

        // since they are not the same, the rest makes little sense...

        // make it dirty
        currentRevision.setTextData("CHANGED " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        // perform merge in CMT transaction
        utx.begin();
        doc = em.merge(doc);
        utx.commit();  // --> ERROR!!!

        // get first content
        content = doc.getContentList().stream().findFirst().get();

        // get current revision
        currentRevision = content.getCurrentRevision();
        System.out.println("currentRevision: " + currentRevision);

        // get last revision
        lastRevision = content.getRevisionList().stream().reduce((prev, curr) -> curr).get();
        System.out.println("lastRevision: " + lastRevision);

        // test equality
        equals = Objects.equals(currentRevision, lastRevision);
        System.out.println("2. equals? " + equals);

        // test identity
        same = currentRevision == lastRevision;
        System.out.println("2. same? " + same);
    }
}
```

since they are not the same:

1. if I enable cascading on both properties, an Exception is thrown

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
       Multiple representations of the same entity [it.shape.edea2.jpa.ContentRevision#1] are being merged. 
           Detached: [ContentRevision@430639650]; 
           Detached: [ContentRevision@1777954561]
   ```
2. if I disable cascade on current, the change get lost.

the strange thing is that running this test outside the container results in successful execution.

Maybe it's lazy loading (hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true), maybe something else, but it's definitely **NOT SAFE**.

I wonder if there's a way to get the same instance.

Comment: Imho for the third point i'd say that there will be the same instance if one of both is lazily loaded but if both are eagerly fetched I think it depends on the underlying implementation. very good question !

Comment: @Gab Thanks ;) I think this depends on cache too... but the specification is very cloudy about this topic.

Comment: If you achieve your pointer needs to the current revision with a simple int instead? You can implement a getCurrentRevision like revisionList.get(currentRevision). Although is true that it may complicate HQL querys over the CurrentRevision, but depends on your needs.

Comment: It's not optimal: you introduce a functional dependency to `order(revisionList)`, so you have to safeguard that the order does not change, or if change you have to *always* update the index too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to cascade merge when the same entity is referenced twice?

Yes. If you manage an instance of `Content`, then it's `Content.revisionList` and `Content.current` are managed as well. Changes in any of those will be persisted when flushing the entity manager. You don't have to call `EntityManager.merge(...)` manually, unless you're dealing with transient objects that need to be merged.

If you create a new `ContentRevision`, then call `persist(...)` instead of `merge(...)` with that new instance and make sure it has a managed reference to the parent `Content`, also add it to the content's list.

> Are Content.current and Content.revisionList[i] the same instance?

Yes, should be. Test it to be sure.

> Content.current is always a member of Content.revisionList (think about Content.current as a "pointer").

You could do that check in in SQL with a check constraint; or in Java, although you'd have to be sure the `revisionList` is fetched. By default it's lazy fetched, meaning Hibernate will run another query for this list if you access the `getRevisionList()` method. And for that you need a running transaction, otherwise you'll be getting a `LazyInitializationException`.

You could instead load the list [eagerly](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/), if that's what you want. Or you could define a [entity graph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) to be able to support both strategies in different queries.

> Users can modify Content.current.textData, but saves Content (cascade merge)

See my first paragraph above, Hibernate should save changes on any managed entity automatically.

> Users can delete ContentRevision

```
if (content.getRevisionList().remove(revision))
    entityManager.remove(revision);

if (revision.equals(content.getCurrentRevision())
    content.setCurrentRevision(/* to something else */);
```

> Users can delete Content (cascade remove to ContentRevision)

Here I'd prefer to ensure that in the database schema, for instance

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (content_id) REFERENCES content (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

---

### UPDATE

As requested, I wrote a test. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jabu10245/0c66e018fae053376231) for the implementations of `Content` and `ContentRevision` I used.

I had to make one important change though: `Content.current` cannot really be `@NotNull`, especially not the DB field, because if it were, then we couldn't persist a content and revision at the same time, since both have no ID yet. Hence the field must be allowed to be `NULL` initially.

As a workaround I added the following method to `Content`:

```
@Transient // ignored in JPA
@AssertTrue // javax.validation
public boolean isCurrentRevisionInList() {
    return current != null && getRevisionList().contains(current);
}
```

Here the validator ensures that the there is always a non-null `current` revision *and* that it is contained in the revision list.

Now here are my tests.

This one proves that the references are the same (Question 3) *and* that it is enough to persist `content` where `current` and `revisionList[0]` is referencing the same instance (question 2):

```
@Test @InSequence(0)
public void shouldCreateContentAndRevision() throws Exception {

    // create java objects, unmanaged:
    Content content = Content.create("My first test");

    assertNotNull("content should have current revision", content.getCurrent());
    assertSame("content should be same as revision's parent", content, content.getCurrent().getContent());
    assertEquals("content should have 1 revision", 1, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertSame("the list should contain same reference", content.getCurrent(), content.getRevisionList().get(0));

    // persist the content, along with the revision:
    transaction.begin();
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    entityManager.persist(content);
    transaction.commit();

    // verify:
    assertEquals("content should have ID 1", Long.valueOf(1), content.getId());
    assertEquals("content should have one revision", 1, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertNotNull("content should have current revision", content.getCurrent());
    assertEquals("revision should have ID 1", Long.valueOf(1), content.getCurrent().getId());
    assertSame("current revision should be same reference", content.getCurrent(), content.getRevisionList().get(0));
}
```

The next ensures that it's still true after loading the entity:

```
@Test @InSequence(1)
public void shouldLoadContentAndRevision() throws Exception {
    Content content = entityManager.find(Content.class, Long.valueOf(1));
    assertNotNull("should have found content #1", content);

    // same checks as before:
    assertNotNull("content should have current revision", content.getCurrent());
    assertSame("content should be same as revision's parent", content, content.getCurrent().getContent());
    assertEquals("content should have 1 revision", 1, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertSame("the list should contain same reference", content.getCurrent(), content.getRevisionList().get(0));
}
```

And even when updating it:

```
@Test @InSequence(2)
public void shouldAddAnotherRevision() throws Exception {
    transaction.begin();
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    Content content = entityManager.find(Content.class, Long.valueOf(1));
    ContentRevision revision = content.addRevision("My second revision");
    entityManager.persist(revision);
    content.setCurrent(revision);
    transaction.commit();

    // re-load and validate:
    content = entityManager.find(Content.class, Long.valueOf(1));

    // same checks as before:
    assertNotNull("content should have current revision", content.getCurrent());
    assertSame("content should be same as revision's parent", content, content.getCurrent().getContent());
    assertEquals("content should have 2 revisions", 2, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertSame("the list should contain same reference", content.getCurrent(), content.getRevisionList().get(1));
}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM content;
 id | version | current_content_revision_id 
----+---------+-----------------------------
  1 |       2 |                           2
```

### UPDATE 2

It was hard to reproduce that situation on my machine, but I got it to work. Here is what I've done so far:

I changed all `@OneToMany` relations to use lazy fetching (the default) and rerun the following test case:

```
@Test @InSequence(3)
public void shouldChangeCurrentRevision() throws Exception {
    transaction.begin();
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    Document document = entityManager.find(Document.class, Long.valueOf(1));
    assertNotNull(document);
    assertEquals(1, document.getContentList().size());
    Content content = document.getContentList().get(0);
    assertNotNull(content);
    ContentRevision revision = content.getCurrent();
    assertNotNull(revision);
    assertEquals(2, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertSame(revision, content.getRevisionList().get(1));
    revision.setTextData("CHANGED");
    document = entityManager.merge(document);
    content = document.getContentList().get(0);
    revision = content.getCurrent();
    assertSame(revision, content.getRevisionList().get(1));
    assertEquals("CHANGED", revision.getTextData());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The test passed with lazy fetching. Note that lazy fetching requires it to be executed within a transaction.

For some reason the content revision instance you're editing is *not* the same as the one in the one-to-many list. To reproduce that I've modified my test as follows:

```
@Test @InSequence(4)
public void shouldChangeCurrentRevision2() throws Exception {
    transaction.begin();
    Document document = entityManager.find(Document.class, Long.valueOf(1));
    assertNotNull(document);
    assertEquals(1, document.getContentList().size());
    Content content = document.getContentList().get(0);
    assertNotNull(content);
    ContentRevision revision = content.getCurrent();
    assertNotNull(revision);
    assertEquals(2, content.getRevisionList().size());
    assertSame(revision, content.getRevisionList().get(1));
    transaction.commit();

    // load another instance, different from the one in the list:
    revision = entityManager.find(ContentRevision.class, revision.getId());
    revision.setTextData("CHANGED2");

    // start another TX, replace the "current revision" but not the one
    // in the list:
    transaction.begin();
    document.getContentList().get(0).setCurrent(revision);
    document = entityManager.merge(document); // here's your error!!!
    transaction.commit();

    content = document.getContentList().get(0);
    revision = content.getCurrent();
    assertSame(revision, content.getRevisionList().get(1));
    assertEquals("CHANGED2", revision.getTextData());
}
```

And there, I got exactly your error. Then I modified the cascading setting on the `@OneToMany` mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "content", cascade = { PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE }, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ContentRevision> revisionList;
```

And the error disappeared :-) ... *because I removed `CascadeType.MERGE`.*

Comment: Database triggers / cascade etc is always a very bad idea when using an ORM (entityManager state will be dirty after a flush)

Comment: I agree on the last point. In this case however, the cascading is already set up in the JPA mapping, so the `ON DELETE CASCADE` does nothing different, really. On the other hand, if there are DB operations occuring outside JPA, or if you would manually delete one `content` using plain SQL, then it's more safe to have that cascaded.

Comment: @jabu.10245 I'm still unsure it is safe, especially in complex cases where there's also a `@Version` attribute on child entity. If you can show some evidence for 2. and 3. (yes, I'm lazy ;)) I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. Forgot to mention that i've used Arquillian and JUnit for the testing part. DB is PostgreSQL 8.4, server is running Wildfly 8.2.0

Comment: Alas, I cannot accept yet (but +1!): there is a counterexample, see updated question.

Comment: So we can conclude: it's safe to use a double relation, with double cascade merge, iff lazy loading always happens within the same transaction (to be precise: persistence context) used to load the parent entity (making lazy loading quite useless, in this scenario). Thank you again, you made me understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @Michele Regarding lazy/eager fetching, have a look at [this blog post](http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-entity-graphs/). It describes how you might conditionally load a `@OneToMany` relation with lazy or eager option.